# How to open a UI-Bootstrap modal from an AngularJS controller and capture selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to launch a modal from an AngularJS controller and then capture the users selection from a nested list. Here is my current attempt in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kug7K9FvhuQfrenMJrTL?p=preview).

script.js

```
    $scope.categoryList = [
                            { name: 'Catégorie 1' },
                            {
                                name: 'Catégorie 2',
                                segments: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'Segment 1',
                                        values: [
                                            { name: 'Valeur 1' },
                                            { name: 'Valeur 2' }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    { name: 'Segment 2' }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Catégorie 3',
                                segments: [
                                    {   name: 'Segment 1',
                                        values: [
                                            { name: 'Valeur 1' },
                                            { name: 'Valeur 2' },
                                            { name: 'Valeur 3' },
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    { name: 'Segment 2' }
                                ]
                            },
                            { name: 'Catégorie 4' },
                            { name: 'Catégorie 5' }
                        ];

                        var catList='';

                        for ( var i=0; i < $scope.categoryList.length; i ++) {
                            var category = $scope.categoryList[i];
                             catList +='<li class="dd-item" class="dd-item" data-id="1"> '+
                             '<div class="dd-handle">'+category.name+'</div> ';
                            if(category.segments){
                                catList +='<ol class="dd-list"> ';
                                for( var j=0; j < category.segments.length; j ++){
                                 var segment = category.segments[j];
                                    catList +='<li class="dd-item"> ' +
                                    '<div class="dd-handle">'+segment.name+'</div> ' ;
                                    if(segment.values){
                                        catList =+ '<ol class="dd-list"> ' ;
                                        for( var k=0; k < segment.values.length; k ++){
                                        var value = segment.values[k];
                                            catList +='<li class="dd-item"> ' +
                                            '<div class="dd-handle" value="" ng-click="setSelectedSegment(value)">'+value.name+'</div>';
                                        }


                                    }
                                    else {
                                        catList +='</li></ol>';
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                catList +='</li> ';
                            }
                        }

                        $scope.catList=catList ;
                        console.log( $scope.catList);
$scope.modalDisplay = ' <div ng-controller="modalCtrl" class="modalsegment" >' +
                    ' <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html" >' +
                    ' <div class="modal-header">' +
                    ' <button type="button" class="close"  ng-click="close()">' +
                    '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>' +
                    ' <h5 class="popup-header">Sélection de la segmentation</h5> </div> ' +
                    '<div class="modal-body" style=" background: #f8fafb"> ' +
                    '<div class="dd" id="nestable"> ' +
                    '<ol class="dd-list"> ' +
                    // add list LI
                    catList

                    ' </ol> </div> </div> ' +
                    '<div class="modal-footer"> </div> ' +
                    '</script> ' +
                    '<button class="safe btn btn-default btn-white btn-segmentation" ng-click="open()">{{ selected ? selected.name : Segmentation }}</button> </div>';
                    $('#showModal').append($scope.modalDisplay);
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="modalCtrl" class="modalsegment" >
                                                    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html" >
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <button type="button" class="close"  ng-click="close()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                                            <h5 class="popup-header">Sélection de la segmentation</h5>
                                                            <!-- <small class="font-bold">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</small>-->
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body" style=" background: #f8fafb">
                                                            <div class="dd" id="nestable">
                                                                <ol class="dd-list">
                                                                    <li class="dd-item" class="dd-item" data-id="1" ng-repeat="category in categoryList">

                                                                        <div class="dd-handle">{{ category.name }}</div>

                                                                        <ol class="dd-list" ng-if="category.segments">
                                                                            <li class="dd-item" ng-repeat="segment in category.segments">

                                                                                <div class="dd-handle">{{ segment.name }}</div>

                                                                                <ol class="dd-list" ng-if="segment.values">
                                                                                    <li class="dd-item" ng-repeat="value in segment.values">
                                                                                        <div class="dd-handle" value="" ng-click="setSelectedSegment(value)">{{ value.name }}</div>
                                                                                    </li>
                                                                                </ol>
                                                                            </li>
                                                                        </ol>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ol>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </script>
                                                    <button class="safe btn btn-default btn-white btn-segmentation" ng-click="open()">{{ selected ? selected.name : 'Segmentation' }}</button>
                                                </div>
```

Comment: I'm a little uncertain what you asking for. Could you elaborate/clarify a little more?

Comment: this is a new post,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795165/angular-js-modal-add-new-controller-to-define-modal-content
 hope you will understand my issue

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the kind of thing you are looking to do? (see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wlAPafZqbsMMq51hYbwN?p=preview).)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-rc.0" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.1" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .popup h1{
        margin:0;
        padding:1rem;
        background-color:#eee;
      }
      .popup .list{
        padding:1rem;
        max-height:20rem;
        overflow-y:auto;
      }
      .popup .list .category{
        margin-left:1rem;
      }
      .popup .list .segment{
        margin-left:3rem;
      }
      .popup .list .value{
        padding-left:5rem;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .popup .list .value:hover{
        background-color:#eee;
      }
      .popup .list .value.selected{
        color:red;
        background-color:#ddd;
      }
      .popup .tools{
        padding:1rem;
        background-color:#eee;
        text-align:right;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="main">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <button ng-click="open()">Select Segment: {{ selected ? selected.name : "None"}}</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="popup.html">
      <div class='popup'>
        <h1>Please make a selection</h1>

        <div class='list'>
          <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <div class='category'>{{category.name}}</div>
            <div ng-repeat="segment in category.segments">
              <div class='segment'>{{segment.name}}</div>
              <div ng-repeat="value in segment.values">
                <div class='value' ng-class="{'selected': value.selected}" ng-click="setSelected(value);">{{value.name}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='tools'>
          <button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
          <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script>

      var app = angular.module('demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
      app.controller('main', function($scope, $modal){
        $scope.selected = null;
        $scope.open = function(){
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'popup.html',
            controller: 'popup',
            size: 'lg'
          });

          modalInstance.result.then(function(selected){
            $scope.selected = selected;
          })
        }

      });

      app.controller('popup', function($scope, $modalInstance){
        $scope.categories = [
          { name: 'Category 1' },
          {
            name: 'Category 2',
            segments: [
              {
                name: 'Segment 1',
                values: [
                  { name: 'Value 1' },
                  { name: 'Value 2' }
                ]
              },
              { name: 'Segment 2' }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'Category 3',
            segments: [
              { name: 'Segment 1' },
              { name: 'Segment 2' }
            ]
          },
          { name: 'Category 4' },
          { name: 'Category 5' }
        ];

        $scope.selected = null;
        $scope.setSelected = function(value){
          console.dir(value);
          for(var i in $scope.categories){
            var category = $scope.categories[i];
            for(var j in category.segments){
              var segment = category.segments[j];
              for(var k in segment.values){
                segment.values[k].selected = false;
              }
            }
          }
          value.selected = true;
          $scope.selected = value;
        }
        $scope.ok = function(){
          $modalInstance.close($scope.selected);
        }
        $scope.cancel = function(){
          $modalInstance.dismiss();
        }

      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```