# Modal Instance not resolving input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use AngularUI modal's and I cannot seem to figure out why it is not resolving my variables.

**Function that opens the modal and the modal instance**

```
$scope.openModal = function (size, cert) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        template: 'ModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            certs: function () {
                return $scope.certification;
            }
        }
   });

   modalInstance.result.then(function () {});
};
```

**Modal Controller some stuff in here is leftover from debugging**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $filter, $modalInstance, certs) {

     console.log(certs);

     var results = $filter('filter')(certs, {id: id})[0];

     $scope.cert = results;

     $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
}]);
```

The main issue is that when it gets into the controller I am getting undefined for certs even though it should be resolved by the openModal function. I was following the official angular UI tutorial on how to do them here: [Angular UI Bootstrap Modals](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Comment: This stackoverflow answer might help you, i think
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768946/how-to-open-a-ui-bootstrap-modal-from-an-angularjs-controller-and-capture-select

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't able to find what I was looking for in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your injection of 'certs' into your controller, you need to add it to the name declaration as well as the function.

```js
angular.module('myApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$modalInstance', 'certs', function ($scope, $filter, $modalInstance, certs) {
```